# Eclipse EE IDE Gives Errors in code yet still runs

Tags: java, eclipse

So I just installed Eclipse on my computer, which I just got a new hard drive for, and I have this weird problem. I installed the JDK, and eclipse, and got it up running and looked at my screen. The first thing I saw was like a million errors that weren't there on my other computer. But when I ran the code, it still works perfectly fine. 
Here is a picture 
[image: My errors, notice how the code still output correctly]

Comment: Could you post the description of any of the error messages?

Comment: Eclipse is likely not registering that as a Java source file, for some reason.

Comment: They shouldn't be errors. It looks like eclipse isn't reading up all the native types in the java. 
Do you see the JRESystem library in the package explorer?

Comment: All the errors have something to do with "can not be resolved"; I do see the JRESystem library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your project folder "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path" then choose tab "Libraries". Ensure your JRE System Library is set correctly. If set, you can double click on it and check it's configuration if not, press "Add Library" choose "JRE System Library" and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I fooled around with it a bit, and got it to work for the project I changed it for. Is there a way I can change this for all of my projects/set a default?

Comment: Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs  and Execution Environments ensure you have those also set accordingly